# Can an iframe only show a certain area of the page?

Tags: html, iframe, iframe-resizer

:) I'm trying to understand how works Iframe when we want to show only a "section" on the src Page.

https://www.cxtv.com.br/tv-ao-vivo/rede-brasil-de-televisao-rbtv
On this Page for example I want to create an Iframe that shows only the video but cutting the rest of the Page it looks different from PC and phone because of the size of the Iframe

I created this one
codepen.io/Felipe-Moraes-the-vuer/pen/PoVeKeJ

Comment: Whybdon’t younjust include the video on your own site directly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.